# How to filter/annotate prefetched objects in django (more efficiently)?

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset, django-filter

I would like to filter queryset, with prefetch_related objects. This code works, but I would like to write it more efficiently. Do you have any idea ?

```
queryset = Song.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('harmonies', queryset=Harmony.objects.filter(someQuery)))

for s in queryset:
    if s.harmonies.count() > 0:
         songs.append(s.id)
queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=songs)
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(h_count=Count('harmonies')).exclude(h_count=0)
```

Thank you , for your help.

Comment: Is the problem with the second query the `someQuery` part? Can you show what that is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Query Related Field Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525771/django-query-related-field-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries), so:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

queryset = Song.objects.filter(
    Exists(Harmony.objects.filter(someQuery, song_id=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

Here the `song_id=…` is the `ForeignKey` from `Harmony` to `song`, so that might be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I need to prefetch related objects too. It's necessary for my purpose. Do you have any idea how to efficiently merge this too filters ?

Comment: @Bumaza: you can still add a `Prefetch` object, simply add the `.prefetch_related` clause after the `.filter(...)`.