# Select all foreign keys from the foreign key table in django

Tags: django, django-models

Let's imagine I have 2 models:

```
Class Tree(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

Class Apple(models.Model):
    tree = models.ForeignKey(Tree, related_name="apples")
```

How do I select all the **Trees** that have **Apples**.
I mean I want to select all the **Trees** that exist in **Apple** Model from an instance of `Tree`.

I think I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tree.id, tree.title
FROM apple JOIN tree ON apple.tree = tree.id
```

Untill now i have written 2 queries and they are working but I think they are not the best practices to do it:

```
Tree.objects.filter(
    apples__tree__in=Apple.objects.all().values_list("tree")
).distinct()
 
Tree.objects.filter(apples__tree__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: In this link you can find the best practice : [Django Query Related Field Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525771/django-query-related-field-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the relation for 'NULL' directly

```
Trees.objects.filter(apples__isnull=False).distinct()
```

P.S. If you want the exact query, you can write it like this (but you'll only get the dictionaries, not a Tree object):

```
Apple.objects.order_by().values('tree__id', 'tree__title').distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The problem is that I don't want to use `isnull` because in my query it will add `WHERE tree.id IS NOT NULL`. I want a query that does this without this `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Well, wha't the problems with the basic SQL construct if that achieves your goal? Any specific reason?

Comment: I think it's faster this way in larger queries because it doesn't check `WHERE` clause it's just simple `SELECT *`, your query will work fine, what I need is query optimization.

Comment: Don't optimize unless you have a specific performance constraints and are violating them. Unless you can meaningfully measure it, it's non-existent

Comment: @MojixCoder I've added another query to the answer. Please **accept** if that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use django aggregates.

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.annotate(page_count=Count('page')).filter(page_count__gte=2).count()
```

Comment: I believe you shouldn't copy-paste solutions from the other questions with completely different models..